# failing to download a dependencies with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, sendgrid

I'm trying to use this code in the link bellow : https://github.com/dmiszkiewicz/sendgrid-scala but i can't download dependency org.miszkiewicz#sendgrid-scala_2.12;0.2-SNAPSHOT, i get this error:

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.miszkiewicz#sendgrid-scala_2.12;0.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.miszkiewicz:sendgrid-scala_2.12:0.2-SNAPSHOT (/Users/aicha/Projets/data-providers/project/FruitionDataProvidersBuild.scala#L62)
[warn]        +- com.fruitionsciences:sendgrid-mailer_2.12:0.1
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last sendgrid-mailer/*:update' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last sendgrid-mailer/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[error] (sendgrid-mailer/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.miszkiewicz#sendgrid-scala_2.12;0.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] (sendgrid-mailer/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.miszkiewicz#sendgrid-scala_2.12;0.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

i'm working with scala 2.12, Does anybody have an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Scala 2.11 to use this dependency from Sonatype repo. As you may see [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/miszkiewicz/), there is build of sendgrid only for Scala 2.11 in Sonatype repo, not for Scala 2.12.

Or maybe, it will be better for you to just use [sendgrid-java](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java).

Comment: can i use it for Scala development

Comment: If you run your Scala program using JVM, yes, you can.